# Microsoft ASP.NET Web API Odata nuget package is failing to install

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, nuget-package

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Data.Edm (= 5.0.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Data.OData (= 5.0.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Spatial (≥ 5.0.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Net.Http (≥ 2.0.20710.0 && < 2.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Spatial (= 5.0.1)'.
Already referencing a newer version of 'System.Spatial'.
```

Anyone got any ideas? why this package is not install? [Google search is empty](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22Already+referencing+a+newer+version+of+%27System.Spatial%27.%22&oq=%22Already+referencing+a+newer+version+of+%27System.Spatial%27.%22&gs_l=hp.3...959.4746.0.5288.7.7.0.0.0.0.112.663.6j1.7.0.les;..0.0...1c.Kem4qXSjOus&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=9f3de7f9ee57ed80&biw=1120&bih=572)

Comment: Also encountering this problem.

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1834383.aspx/1?Microsoft+ASP+NET+Web+API+Odata+nuget+package+is+failing+to+install+  has a little more info now.  They should be fixing it.

Comment: I had this issue. After I updated to EF5 I was able to install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex James posted on [his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2012/08/15/odata-support-in-asp-net-web-api.aspx) that this has been fixed.

The issue was that ODataLib was released after this OData package was released and that broke the dependencies (version numbers didn't add up). Everything works now, at least for me.